# Handle latest query response Android

Tags: java, android, performance, kotlin, networking

I have a drop down which lets you select the name of the country and then in the other bottom the province/state is populated based on the country selected.
When the user selects the country, a query is made and then province is updated respectively
I am running into a scenario where there's a race condition between the query response arrival, which ends up displaying the incorrect data . How should I handle this ?

eg: User selects country A, query is fired, network is slow, meanwhile user changes the country to B and then another request is fired, The response of B comes back quickly, but response of A comes after, Now the screen is in a state where country says B but the province are of A

Notice: I don't want to block the country selector while the query response is being awaited
any suggestions on resolving this ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You may want to add a simple filter on your query response, such
   that the code to display runs if the response matches the current
   query. Configure your callback code carefully, and you can have only the latest
   response displayed, since you know which country is currently selected.
   (Admittedly, this might not the *best* way to do this, but it should work.)
2. More generally, you would have to develop this with some combination of network request(s) and caching/local database.

   - If the size of your dataset is not too large, or if it is not going to be updated too often, you might simply want to put it into a local database, e.g. Room DB.
   - If your data doesn't match this specification and it is subject to future updates in the back-end, but the overall dataset is pretty small, try caching the dataset (countries and provinces) at app start. This way your network calls are light, you always have the latest data, your UI is no longer dependent on asynchronous operations, and your code is simpler. You could also use data binding here, if appropriate.
   - If your dataset is very large such that fetching it all at app start is an unacceptable overhead, only then should you work purely with network request(s) each time the user changes a filter option. One option is that your callback code is configured to ignore any response that doesn't relate to the currently selected option. Another option is that your HTTP-related schema, for request and/or response, can contain some information about which "country" generated the HTTP request so that you can check for it in the response object. (The latter option can be considered overkill in most cases, but sometimes in complex scenarios, you might have to do such stuff for one or more reasons, such as functional definition, simplicity, neatness, etc.)

P.S.: I assume you are already using appropriate libraries for HTTP calls.